# [C#]: Maximum timeout of 600 seconds was reached while waiting for task to complete

Tags: c#, timeout

In my test, I have a *for* loop, that runs a powershell script, which sometimes takes a longer time to execute. I've got an error like this: **Maximum timeout of 600 seconds was reached while waiting for task to complete**. I would like to ask, whether this error happens when the whole test takes more than 600 seconds to complete or one script run is longer than 600 seconds?

P.S. I run that test from Command Line

Would this help me? If not, what should I change?

```
process.WaitForExit(1000 * 60 * 60); //Wait up to one hour
```

EDIT (Whole exception):

> Maximum timeout of 600 seconds was reached while waiting for task to
>   complete: C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit 2.6.4\bin\nunit-console.exe
>   "C:\Tests\resources\test_scripts\api-tests-hd\Installers\Test1\bin\Release\Test1.dll"
>   /xml:"C:\Tests\Results\Test1\39.xml". 2018-05-17
>   06:49:01,933 ERROR StarterConsole.HttpPost - FileNotFoundException
>   Writing to fileStream to dataStream in HttpUploadFile!
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file
>   'C:\Tests\Results\Test1\39.xml'. File name:
>   'C:\Tests\Results\Test1\39.xml'    at
>   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess
>   access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32
>   bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String
>   msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
>   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess
>   access, FileShare share)    at
>   StarterConsole.HttpPost.HttpUploadFile(Uri postLocation, String file,
>   String paramName, String contentType, Dictionary`2 postItems, Int32
>   retries) in
>   C:\repos\starterconsole\StarterConsole\Http\HttpPost.cs:line 293

Comment: What are you using to execute these tests? Please post the entire exception and stacktrace for this error.

Comment: @Jerodev Done, exception uploaded.